# node.js error: uv_signal_start EINVA

Tags: node.js, opa

I built the opa from source on a 32bit Debian linux(uname says it is i686) and when I issued "opa create example" on the command line I got this error message:

```
node.js:593
          throw errnoException(errno, 'uv_signal_start');
                ^
Error: uv_signal_start EINVAL
    at errnoException (node.js:388:13)
    at process.on.process.addListener (node.js:593:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/opa/stdlib/server.opp/serverNodeJsPackage.js:12:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:454:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:472:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/opa/stdlib/stdlib.qmljs/stdlib.core.web.resource.opx/a.js:4:20)
```

Node.js version is v0.9.3-pre and it works (checked it with a simple hello world javascript).
Opa version says: Opa compiler (c) MLstate -- version 1.0.7 -- build 3524.

Answer (score -1):

Installing the v0.8.12 node.js version resolved my issue.